# Slow down gganimate in R

Tags: r, gganimate

How do I slow the plot below, down?  I am trying to step through the days a bit slower.  This is three years worth of data shown by day.  Each day should be about 0.25 seconds.

[image]

The code I am using to build this plot is below:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

df_daily %>%
    ggplot(aes(longitude, latitude)) +
    geom_point(aes(alpha = a)) +
    transition_time(flu_day) +
    ease_aes('linear', interval = 0.001) +
    labs(title = 'Date: {frame_time}')
```

Comment: Can you make your problem [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
a <- df_daily %>%
    ggplot(aes(longitude, latitude)) +
    geom_point(aes(alpha = a)) +
    transition_time(flu_day) +
    ease_aes('linear', interval = 0.001) +
    labs(title = 'Date: {frame_time}')



animate(a, 
        duration = 274, # = 365 days/yr x 3 years x 0.25 sec/day = 274 seconds
        fps  =  [pick how smooth you want],
        nframes = [...or pick it here])
```